# Installed numpy for pypy but get " TypeError: readonly attribute '__module__' "

Tags: python, numpy, pypy

I've installed numpy in the recommended way for PyPy 6.0:

```
./pypy -m ensurepip
./pip install -U pip wheel
./pypy -m pip install numpy
```

However, this does not work (on Ubuntu 16.04): this installation succeeds but I get the following when I try to import numpy:

```
Python 2.7.13 (ab0b9caf307d, Apr 24 2018, 18:04:42)
[PyPy 6.0.0 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jwimberl/src/pypy2-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/home/jwimberl/src/pypy2-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/home/jwimberl/src/pypy2-v6.0.0-linux64/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 44, in <module>
    arange.__module__ = 'numpy'
TypeError: readonly attribute '__module__'
```

I've seen other questions on SO about pypy/numpy but they are all >3 years old and I'm not sure they are up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an incompatibility between numpy 1.16.0 and pypy-v6.0, [more details here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12740). It'll be fixed in the next pypy release (coming soon), but in the mean time, you should probably use numpy 1.15.4 instead (e.g. using `./pypy -m pip install 'numpy<1.16'`).

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I didn't find this result when googling around, thought the error was quite similar (the github issue pops up as an 'AttributeError' during installation of a dependent package, whereas I got the 'TypeError' during import).